# Can we integrate payment gateway or I have to go with inApp-purchase

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase, payment

I want to add a feature in my iOS app where user can enable the paid service - In that paid service user can can download the data/content from other hardware to mobile app via Bluetooth service.

Here my question is:

1. Should I integrate third party payment gateway for the paid service?
2. Or Forcefully I have to go with default inApp-Purchase?

Which approach supported by the Apple? - I wanted to go with approach 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Apple requires you to use Apple's in-app-purchase for this.  Going around their in-app-purchase will get your app banned from the App Store (see Epic battle, etc).

> 3.3.3 Without Apple’s prior written approval or as permitted under Section 3.3.25 (In-App Purchase API), an Application may not provide, unlock or enable additional features or functionality through distribution mechanisms other than the App Store, Custom App Distribution or TestFlight.

The full agreements are here:  https://developer.apple.com/support/terms/

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the answer!
is there any ways to add payment gateway instead of inApp-purchase?
can we use web page for the payment gateway?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but my understanding is "No." This is what the lawsuit with Epic is about.  If you are accepting payment in your app - or linking to a separate page to accept payment - then you have to use Apple's in-app-purchase.

Comment: As I said above, if you try to go around Apple then they will remove your app once they realize you have.  It's against the rules of the Apple iOS App Store developer agreement.  You are trying to avoid paying them their cut and they don't like that :)

Comment: If you are a small developer you may be eligible for the Small Business Program which provides for reduced fees on App Store transactions (15% instead of 30% currently). https://developer.apple.com/app-store/small-business-program/